# insert custom HTML content to checkbox containers of items 'checked'

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Basically; what I am trying to achieve is '**if and only if**' an element in my static HTML form is checked; so if a checkbox is checked > then the user hits the '***submit***' button. The items or checkboxes that are not checked, simply disappear, I have this with the below snippet of code.

```
    $("input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)").parent().hide();
```

OK, so the ones that are not checked hide correctly as they are supposed too, perfect! The problem is: I need the checkbox container div(s) to populate with unique HTML on the next page after the user has 'selected / checked' and then hit submit button. So currently on the next page; the non-checked items hide, and the form elements hide, so all that is perfect. So it's just the black (currently grey background) wrapper divs of the check boxes / items that are checked. But I just need to invoke custom HTML in each one.

***Again; user flow: Static Homepage HTML form > user selects checkboxes > hit's submit > next page all non-checked items hide, check boxes themself all hide, but their respective wrapper containers remain - and I simply want custom HTML to appear in each at this point. As opposed to being blank*** So, the insertion of custom HTML in each of these divs at this point is my struggle

---

**Below is the full pages code:**

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css">
</head>

<style>
  #item1 {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #333;
  }
  #item2 {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #333;
  }
  #item3 {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #333;
  }
  #item4 {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #333;
  }
  .space {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="container" id="records" style="background-color:#fff; width: 400px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <br/>

    <div class="row" id="item1" class="box">
      Item 1 Details for the PDF test.
      <br>

      <input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="sample[]" value="red" /> <em>This</em> is a checkbox1
      <br />

    </div>

    <div class="space"></div>

    <div class="row" id="item2" class="box">
      Item 2 Details for the PDF test.
      <br>

      <input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="sample[]" value="red" /> <em>This</em> is a checkbox2
      <br />

    </div>

    <div class="space"></div>

    <div class="row" id="item3" class="box">
      Item 3 Details for the PDF test.
      <br>

      <input type="checkbox" id="check3" name="sample[]" value="red" /> <em>This</em> is a checkbox3
      <br />

    </div>

    <div class="space"></div>

    <div class="row" id="item4" class="box">
      Item 4 Details for the PDF test.
      <br>

      <input type="checkbox" id="check4" name="sample[]" value="red" /> <em>This</em> is a checkbox4
      <br />
    </div>

    <div class="space"></div>

    <center>
      <div class="container1">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg download-pdf" href="#" role=button>Download PDF</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </center>

    <div id="print" style="background-color:#fff"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $("#container").css('background', '#fff')

       $('.download-pdf').click(function() {

        $("input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)").parent().hide();

        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');

        pdf.addHTML(document.getElementById('records'), function() {});
        var file = 'test';
        if (typeof doc !== 'undefined') {
          doc.save(file + '.pdf');
        } else if (typeof pdf !== 'undefined') {
          (function() {
            pdf.save(file + '.pdf');
            // $("#item4").hide();

          }, 2000);
        } else {
          alert('Error 0xE001BADF');
        }

      });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There's a submit button?  You mention a "next page", is this code for page 1 or page 2 or both?

Comment: There is just 2 pages total, the submit button just acts as a 'next button' essentially. No data is 'submited' or 'collected'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it helps. Just included all these lines:

```
texts = {
  item1: 'Some <strong>html</strong> gfor item1',
  item2: 'Some <strong>html</strong> gfor item2',
  item3: 'Some <strong>html</strong> gfor item3',
  item4: 'Some <strong>html</strong> gfor item4',
}

notChecked = $("input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)").parent();
notChecked.hide();
yesChecked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").parent();

$.each(yesChecked, function( index, el ) {
  $(el).show().html(texts[$(el).attr('id')]);
});
```

So create a hash texts that will include copy per each container ID, as shown.
Not the most beautiful version ever, but a fast response

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css">
</head>

<style>
  #item1 {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #333;
  }
  #item2 {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #333;
  }
  #item3 {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #333;
  }
  #item4 {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #333;
  }
  .space {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="container" id="records" style="background-color:#fff; width: 400px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <br/>

    <div class="row" id="item1" class="box">
      Item 1 Details for the PDF test.
      <br>

      <input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="sample[]" value="red" /> <em>This</em> is a checkbox1
      <br />

    </div>

    <div class="space"></div>

    <div class="row" id="item2" class="box">
      Item 2 Details for the PDF test.
      <br>

      <input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="sample[]" value="red" /> <em>This</em> is a checkbox2
      <br />

    </div>

    <div class="space"></div>

    <div class="row" id="item3" class="box">
      Item 3 Details for the PDF test.
      <br>

      <input type="checkbox" id="check3" name="sample[]" value="red" /> <em>This</em> is a checkbox3
      <br />

    </div>

    <div class="space"></div>

    <div class="row" id="item4" class="box">
      Item 4 Details for the PDF test.
      <br>

      <input type="checkbox" id="check4" name="sample[]" value="red" /> <em>This</em> is a checkbox4
      <br />
    </div>

    <div class="space"></div>

    <center>
      <div class="container1">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg download-pdf" href="#" role=button>Download PDF</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </center>

    <div id="print" style="background-color:#fff"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      texts = {
        item1: 'Some <strong>html</strong> gfor item1',
        item2: 'Some <strong>html</strong> gfor item2',
        item3: 'Some <strong>html</strong> gfor item3',
        item4: 'Some <strong>html</strong> gfor item4',
      }
      $("#container").css('background', '#fff')

       $('.download-pdf').click(function() {

        notChecked = $("input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)").parent();
        notChecked.hide();
        yesChecked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").parent();

        $.each(yesChecked, function( index, el ) {
          $(el).show().html(texts[$(el).attr('id')]);
        });

        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');

        pdf.addHTML(document.getElementById('records'), function() {});
        var file = 'test';
        if (typeof doc !== 'undefined') {
          doc.save(file + '.pdf');
        } else if (typeof pdf !== 'undefined') {
          (function() {
            pdf.save(file + '.pdf');
            // $("#item4").hide();

          }, 2000);
        } else {
          alert('Error 0xE001BADF');
        }

      });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is nice! And thanks so much for taking a look, however each .html would have to be unique so there would be 4 unique ones, it can't just all be the same, but I gave you an upvote for taking a look! ;)

Comment: Ok, got it, you'l have to loop through them like this:

Comment: $.each(notChecked, function( index, el ) {
  $(el).show().html("Those is not checked :)" + index);
});

Comment: hey, what kind of content you want to add, give me example

Comment: Just say; 4 different HTML text per the 4 areas

Comment: give me a concrete example, cuz there're 2 ways

Comment: I just need one working way, ideally with the least amount of code - to show the content per checked area. Note; if multiple are checked multiple would show as in Question. So, seperate HTML content to appear in each area. With the ability to style inline or out would be great too

Comment: OK, thanks so much! However this broke my previous working functionaliy. Such as the 'generation to pdf' with the button, and also it now no longer hides the non-checked containers / areas as before.

Comment: Haha Now I see what you want - here you go, updated!

Comment: Thanks so much, everything is great except the PDF functionality has stopped working now. The download pdf also triggers the actual download of the static page generated PDF

Comment: Thank you for the help bro, I got it tweaking this snippet of yours. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another version, where you just specify your HTML inside divs with after-submit class:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.0.272/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css">
</head>

<style>
  #item1 {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #333;
  }
  #item2 {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #333;
  }
  #item3 {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #333;
  }
  #item4 {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #333;
  }
  .space {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
  }
  .box .after-submit {
    display: none;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="container" id="records" style="background-color:#fff; width: 400px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <br/>

    <div class="row" id="item1" class="box">
      <div class="after-submit">
        Some <strong>HTML</strong> here 1
      </div>
      <div class="before-submit">
        Item 1 Details for the PDF test.
        <br>

        <input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="sample[]" value="red" /> <em>This</em> is a checkbox1
        <br />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="space"></div>

    <div class="row" id="item2" class="box">
      <div class="after-submit">
        Some <strong>HTML</strong> here 2
      </div>
      <div class="before-submit">

        Item 2 Details for the PDF test.
        <br>

        <input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="sample[]" value="red" /> <em>This</em> is a checkbox2
        <br />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="space"></div>

    <div class="row" id="item3" class="box">
      <div class="after-submit">
        Some <strong>HTML</strong> here 3
      </div>
      <div class="before-submit">
        Item 3 Details for the PDF test.
        <br>

        <input type="checkbox" id="check3" name="sample[]" value="red" /> <em>This</em> is a checkbox3
        <br />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="space"></div>

    <div class="row" id="item4" class="box">
      <div class="after-submit">
        Some <strong>HTML</strong> here 4
      </div>
      <div class="before-submit">
        Item 4 Details for the PDF test.
        <br>

        <input type="checkbox" id="check4" name="sample[]" value="red" /> <em>This</em> is a checkbox4
        <br />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="space"></div>

    <center>
      <div class="container1">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg download-pdf" href="#" role=button>Download PDF</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </center>

    <div id="print" style="background-color:#fff"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $("#container").css('background', '#fff')

       $('.download-pdf').click(function() {

        yesChecked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").closest(".before-submit").hide();
        yesChecked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").closest(".after-submit").show();
        notChecked = $("input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)").parent().parent();
        notChecked.hide();


        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');

        pdf.addHTML(document.getElementById('records'), function() {});
        var file = 'test';
        if (typeof doc !== 'undefined') {
          doc.save(file + '.pdf');
        } else if (typeof pdf !== 'undefined') {
          (function() {
            pdf.save(file + '.pdf');
            // $("#item4").hide();

          }, 2000);
        } else {
          alert('Error 0xE001BADF');
        }

      });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks again for you effort, also love this method -- but it cannot destroy original functionality of generating to PDF with the download button to trigger the pdf generated actual download. Which these options you provided work great! But it destroys the PDF generation / download functionality so I cannot use as a viable option

Comment: The question has turned into a new one if your interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34145059/generate-dynamic-pdf-with-jspdf-library-based-on-user-input-fix-error