# generate dynamic pdf with jsPDF library based on user input (fix error)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf

So, I actually have this functionality working. With the below JS. The problem is upon submit, the next page should not reflect these changes, but instead ***ONLY*** reflect in the generated PDF. Currently the PDF is being generated correctly, but the second page or second view (what is generated in the PDF is shown on the current) this should not be the case, this static page should remain as is and just have the reflected changes viewable in the generated PDF.

*Here is actually the original question - though the scope has transformed into this current question hints the new question, but URL for sample purposes as it may help. [insert custom HTML content to checkbox containers of items 'checked'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34138972/insert-custom-html-content-to-checkbox-containers-of-items-checked)*

```
  texts = {
        item1: 'Item Box 1 Content <strong>html</strong> right here!',
        item2: 'Now its Item Box 2 <strong>html</strong> content here !',
        item3: 'This is the example <strong>html</strong> of Item box 4!',
        item4: 'Item box number 5 <strong>html</strong> content is here!',
      }
      $("#container").css('background', '#fff')

       $('.download-pdf').click(function() {

        notChecked = $("input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)").parent();
        notChecked.hide();
        yesChecked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").parent();

        $.each(yesChecked, function( index, el ) {
          $(el).show().html(texts[$(el).attr('id')]);
        });

     var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');

        pdf.addHTML(document.getElementById('records'), function() {
            // add here

        }); 

        var file = 'test';
        if (typeof doc !== 'undefined') {
            doc.save(file + '.pdf');
        } else if (typeof pdf !== 'undefined') {
            setTimeout(function() {
                pdf.save(file + '.pdf');
                // $("#item4").hide();

            }, 2000);
        } else {
            alert('Error 0xE001BADF');
        }

    });
```

**Attempt:**

```
 var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4'); // moved everything relevant to be called within jsPDF object here

    pdf.addHTML(document.getElementById('records'), function() {
    // add here

    texts = {
        item1: 'Item Box 1 Content <strong>html</strong> right here!',
        item2: 'Now its Item Box 2 <strong>html</strong> content here !',
        item3: 'This is the example <strong>html</strong> of Item box 4!',
        item4: 'Item box number 5 <strong>html</strong> content is here!',
         }

        notChecked =  $("input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)").parent();
        notChecked.hide();
        yesChecked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").parent();

        $.each(yesChecked, function( index, el ) {
          $(el).show().html(texts[$(el).attr('id')]);
        });

    });
```

Comment: Not sure what you want, can you describe simpler and include the snipped?

Comment: Hey Michael - so I just need the selections to generate in the PDF that triggers download. (In order to actually see this happening you have to throw the above code into MAMP or a server). Basically what we did on the last question - except it doesn't occur on page, or in second view. ONLY it shows in the PDF. Actually in our last question it generated in the PDF just fine but it also displayed on the page. It should not display on the page at all, just in that PDF file.

Comment: As you can see in the add here // comment above. that's why I tried moving everything within that jsPDF object. Because all that functionality should ONLY occur in the generated pdf itself.

Comment: Ah so you want the second page to be a PDF not a page, right?

Comment: If yes, you want to trigger download after submission?

Comment: No no no, there should be no second page. Basically the code at the end of last question it worked fine, even generated to PDF but there should be no second page is all. Static page should remain as is, when button is clicked all that happens is PDF is generated via the user input (which works, just the static homepage cannot change)